# Prove that for any integers a and b and c, gcd(a, b) = gcd(a + bc, a + b(c − 1))

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Please help me with this question

> Prove that for any integers $a$ and $b$, 
>   $$\mathrm{gcd}(a, b) = \mathrm{gcd}(a + bc, a + b(c − 1))$$

I tried to prove it but I didn't understand the part of $b(c-1)$

let $d=\mathrm{gcd} (a,b)$

$h=\mathrm{gcd}(a,btac)$

since $d= \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)\implies d|a\:\text{and}\: d|b$ and then
$$
\begin{split}
d|b\:\text{ and }\:d|ac & \implies d|b+ac\\
d|a\:\text{ and }\:d|b +d|ac & \implies d|h
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Where did $c$ come from?

Comment: That's why I have trouble solving it....

Answer (score 3):

For all integers $m,n$, we have $\gcd(m,n) = \gcd(m,n-m)$. By induction, we also have $\gcd(m,n) = \gcd(m,n-km)$, for some integer $k$ (this is Euclidean algorithm). Using that, we have:

$$\gcd(a+bc,a+b(c-1)) = \gcd(a+bc, (a+bc)-(a+b(c-1))) = \gcd(a+bc,b) = \gcd(a,b).$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question should also say "for any integer $c$".

Clearly $\gcd(a,b)\mid a+cb$, because it divides each term separately, and similarly $\gcd(a,b)\mid a+(c-1)b$, so $\gcd(a,b)\mid\gcd(a+cb,a+(c-1)b)$.

Conversely, $\gcd(a+cb,a+(c-1)b)\mid (a+cb)-(a+(c-1)b)=b$. It therefore also divides $cb$ and hence divides $a+cb-cb=a$. So $\gcd(a+cb,a+(c-1)b)\mid\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did after the "Conversely..."

Comment: http://www.mathwords.com/c/converse.htm